# Understanding induction in proof of Perceptron convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, induction

I'm trying to understand the proof of Perceptron convergence ([See Theorem 3](https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~shivaram/teaching/old/cs344+386-s2017/resources/classnote-1.pdf?fbclid=IwAR04t98HNykga86wdT0BrQ0bzRFIqwQbFU2vfNb9sCkvkTKNHq7Hjl9LWY0)). I'm having trouble understanding the induction part ([it follows by induction that..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57PE8.png)). Can anyone explain me how you get from

$$w^{k+1}w^*>w^{k}w^*+\gamma$$
to 
$$w^{k+1}w^*>k\gamma$$

and likewise, from:
$$\vert \vert w^{k+1} \vert \vert^2 \leq \vert \vert w^k \vert \vert ^2 +R^2 $$
to
$$\vert \vert w^{k+1} \vert \vert^2 \leq kR^2 $$

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** 
We have 
$$
w^{k + 1} w^{\star}
> w^k w^{\star} + \gamma.
$$
Now applying the same reasoning as for the first step, we have
$$
w^k w^{\star}
> w^{k - 1} w^{\star} + \gamma.
$$
Combining both equations yields
$$
w^{k + 1} w^{\star}
> w^{k - 1} w^{\star} + \gamma + \gamma
= w^{k - 1} w^{\star} + 2 \gamma.
$$
What happens when we repeat this pattern until we arrive at $w^1 = 0$?

The other inequality follows analogously, where again it is crucial that $w^{1} = 0$, implying $\| w^{1} \|^2 = 0$.